# stopping jquery upon php script if/else clause

Tags: php, jquery, session, authentication, single-page-application

I have created a `SPA` login system with `php`/`mysql`/`jquery`. I am at the point where all my code functions - I am just trying to do some validation. Like, "if textfield is blank, echo 'something'". The if/else statement works from within the `php` script - but the `jquery` is still being executed on form submit, and thus it brings up a password protected page with blank session info.

Here is the script that gets run upon login:

checklogin.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="xxx"; // Mysql password
$db_name="itit"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

if(!$_POST['myusername'] || !$_POST['mypassword']) {
    echo "Username and password cannot be blank!";
    session_destroy();
}
else {
    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=? and password=?");
    $sql->bind_param('ss',$myusername,$mypassword);
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->store_result();//apply to prepare statement
    $numRows = $sql->num_rows;
    if($numRows === 1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        session_destroy();
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see, I have an if statement that checks whether or not the username or password fields are blank. It continues if they aren't, but if they are it is supposed to stop and execute the echo statement inside the if block. I think I need to do something to my jquery to make it recognize that the ajax call should not be executed (or something like that). Here is my jquery:

js/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").load("templates/indexforms.php", function () {
        $("#login").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("checklogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function() {
                $("#main").load("templates/login_success.php");
                $("#login").remove();
                $("#register").remove();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I basically need to stop the submit function from happening...so that the page contents don't change. Again...I am trying to make a single page application, so I am just switching things in and out of a div in my `index.php` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing a check if the fields are blank before you send the post data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#main").load("templates/indexforms.php", function () {
    $("#login").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#myusername').val() != '' && $('#mypassword').val() != '') {
            $.post("checklogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function() {
                $("#main").load("templates/login_success.php");
                $("#login").remove();
                $("#register").remove();
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please enter a Username/Password');
        }
    });
});
```

});